# Modifying Generated web.config file with net core 2 when running on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a webapi 2.0 which I am publishing using ftp to my windows 2012 server running IIS 8.5.

I ran into an issue which I can resolved using this link here;

[Error 405 – Methods not Allowed in ASP.NET Core PUT and DELETE requests](https://www.ryadel.com/en/error-405-methods-not-allowed-asp-net-core-put-delete-requests/)

so by adding;

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

I can fix my PUT and DELETE issues, however whenever I publish I am having to physically edit the web.config to reflect the addition of the above code?

Can anyone tell me how to automatically add this when I publish using ftp with web deploy?

My program.cs has the default build in it;

```
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Comment: In one of my deployments I have a Powershell script to modify the contents of `web.config`, then I execute it as a pre-publish target.

Comment: ok do you have an example you could post I can live with that solution? I assume there no way to pipe into the process when its created then?

Comment: There could be, I'm just not aware of it. `web.config` isn't really part of ASP.NET Core, it's just there for IIS compatibility. I get the impression it wasn't meant to be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I've done is to create a Powershell script that will modify your web.config file however you need and execute it as a Pre-publish Target.

Keep the script in your project directory and update the `.csproj` file so that it will run just before publishing the project:

Left click project name in Visual Studio -> "Edit .csproj" and insert this somewhere inside the `<Project>` tags:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -File Prepublish.ps1" />
</Target>
```

Edit:
My task was simpler, I just needed to remove the `LAUNCHER_ARGS` added to the `<aspNetCore>` element, so I just did a simple string replace with an empty string,

Prepublish.ps1:

```
(Get-Content web.config).Replace(" arguments=`"%LAUNCHER_ARGS%`"", "") | Set-Content web.config
```

Comment: Out of interest how do you edit the file to add it in the correct location?

Comment: Sorry I meant do you have an example of your powershell script?

Comment: I added mine, but my modification wasn't quite as involved as yours so a slightly different approach might be needed.